# Sql Server Connection via EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Although I can connect to the server when I'm using either legacy `SqlConnection` or `Sql Management Studio`, I'm not able to make connection to Sql Server via Entity framework. In addition I've check all following things:

1. Data Source or Server Name or IP address is correct. it is: SKI-PC\
2. I'm sure that my instance name is correct.
3. Remote connections are allowed and also there is no firewall.

The error I'm facing is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Just for clarifying, my connection string in `app.config` is:

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SKI-PC\SEP;initial catalog=Restaurant;user id=sa;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci) for a possible solution.

Comment: So how are you telling EF to use that connection string? I prefer to supply it to the constructor of the DbContext as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674).